# Should I scale time-series features for supervised learning classification?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, feature-engineering, supervised-learning, feature-scaling

I couldn't find an answer to this in the archives so posting this here. I am currently building out a supervised-learning / classification pipeline for time series forecasting (e.g. predicting the class label t+1 periods ahead).

I've extracted a number of auto-regressive features using the [tsfresh](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/) package. I am wondering if I should standardize these values as you typically would in a supervised learning approach (e.g. using one of [Sklearn's scaler functions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)) ?

Comment: Scaling is not a hard requirement, but specific classifiers like neural nets and SVM require scaling.

Comment: I could not add this as a comment since I have not enough reputation.
So I add it here.
Have a look at this.
https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-feature-scaling-bcc0ad75cb35 At th ened of the article you can find other references. Hope it helps